# Issue constructing a query in Rails using Arel and array attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel, rails-postgresql

I'm stuck with the query that checks whether two arrays have one or more elements in common.

Since the query is the part of a much bigger query, I need to use [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) to accomplish this. But the `&&` operator, known as the overlap operator, is not implemented in Arel gem.

There's a [postgres_ext gem](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext) that implements the above mentioned operator and provides a `.overlap` method so that one could construct the query similar to the one I did: `DiscountCondition.arel_table[:target_plan_period_ids].overlap(target_period_ids)`. This produces an SQL where clause that works fine for me: `"\"discount_conditions\".\"target_plan_period_ids\" && '{2}'"`.

But. The thing is some tests in our application failed with the following error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'array' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Column:0x007f23c4995ba8>` (turns out the gem is incompatible with some adapters).

A simple `ActiveRecord` query that works is `DiscountCondition.where('target_plan_period_ids && ARRAY[?]', target_period_ids)` that produces the following SQL query `"SELECT \"discount_conditions\".\"discount_id\" FROM \"discount_conditions\"  WHERE (target_plan_period_ids && ARRAY[2])"`.

So, I wanted to know if anyone faced that issue and succeeded to workaround this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone ever faces the same issue, I ended up [monkey patching the aforementioned functionality](https://gist.github.com/dskecse/07fed1bec56d8c68a9a2) of a `postgres_ext` gem into the project.